# using class in php and displaying results

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I want to display results that i am retrieving from a mysql db in php.

I have a files call db_functions.php with the following :

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

        private $con;

        // constructor
        function __construct() {
            require_once __DIR__.'/db_connect.php';
            // connecting to database
            $db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->con = $db->getDbConnection();
        }

        public function selectUser($id) {

            try {
                $stmt = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id');

                $params = array(':id' => $id);

                $stmt->execute($params);

                return $stmt;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {

                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();

            }

        }

        public function otherSQLfunction($parameter) {
                 // other sql code
        }
}
```

I then call the function with :

```
<?php

     require_once __DIR__.'/db_functions.php';

     $db = new DB_Functions();

     $result = $db->selectUser($id);



?>
```

How do use this function and display a results , lets say i just want it to display the "affID "

Comment: it returns $stmt so use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `selectUser` function and it will either return `$stmt` or `echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();`.

If it returns `$stmt` that variable will be stored in your `$result` variable.

You can then use `$result` however you'd like to do so (`echo $result`, `foreach $result as $item`, etc,).

Comment: Hi Dan, could you perhaps give me a full example, thanks

Comment: What is `$stmt`? What do you get when you `print_r($stmt);`? Is it an array, a string, a number?